# CSS inline-block not respecting margin or padding

Tags: margin, padding, css

I've been experimenting with "display:inline-block" as an alternative to "display:float". All the documentation I've found says properties that can be normally applied to a block element can be applied to an "inline-block" element. Specifically "height", "width", "margin" and "padding" are always listed.

Setting height and width certainly works for me - and I assume everyone else as well, since every example I've found on the web explaining "inline-block" sets one or both.

But setting margin or padding appears to have no effect at all in either IE9 or Firefox 32. And no example I've managed to find sets either one.

I'd really rather use margins and padding, as the content can have varying width. Is there an example somewhere that I've overlooked?

This is an excerpt of what I've been playing with most recently:

```
.lnk2 a {
display: inline-block;
margin: 2px 1em;
padding: 2px 2em;
}

<div class="lnk2">
 <a href="rates/minneapolis-55401.htm">55401</a>
 <a href="rates/minneapolis-55402.htm">55402</a>
 <a href="rates/minneapolis-55403.htm">55403</a>
</div>
```

It doesn't matter what the values used for "margin" or "padding" are. The actual display never changes in either browser.

Also, originally the "div" in the HTLM was "ol" and each "a" was wrapped in an "li" pair. Same result - the above HTML is just trying to simplify things a bit to see if that gets closer to the problem.

Comment: There's no such thing as `display:float`

Comment: Clearly **does** work - http://jsfiddle.net/LsvgqcLy/1/ So something else must be overriding these declarations.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? It might help to explicitly set all four margins and paddings explicitly: margin: 2px 1em 2px 1em; padding: 2px 2em 2px 2em; (and I usually set background-colors while developing, to see what's going on) Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/LsvgqcLy/2/

Comment: It works. You must have other overriding CSS rules. Look at the CSS tab of the developer tools.

Comment: This isn't going anywhere. Please post the real HTML.

Comment: My bad. It does work when I comment out an imported style sheet. Now I have to figure out why - I was under the impression that a rule like ".lnk2 a" or ".lnk2>a", occuring later in the rule list and being "closer" to what I wanted to affect than any previous rule, would take precedence.

Comment: Also yes, that should have been "float: left". Too hasty writing it.

Comment: @AntonTreuenfels So it's a specificity problem? That's OK, we can handle that. We can solve it! As long as we can get to see the real problem. I mean the actual problem, not some "it looks a bit like this" pseudo code.

Comment: It is a specificity problem.  I know which rule in the imported css file is overriding the rule in the <style></style> block in the test page. The imported css (about 6K) is the general "look" of the website, the test page (63K) is the stuff I'm playing with.

Comment: What's the best way to show the code? I doubt I can condense it enough to fit it in one of these comment boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use floated element to remove unwanted spaces

```
.lnk2 a {
display:block;
float:left;
margin: 2px 1em;
padding: 2px 2em;
}
```